# Errormessage with reference module

Tags: nodes

When I want to add a link between two content types I got the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: args in _node_reference_view_settings_validate() (line 161 of /var/www/vhosts/nielsjansen.be/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/references/node_reference/node_reference.module).

Settings were saved but with this error. Is this a problem?

Comment: first google result: http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22Undefined+index:+args+in+_node_reference_view_settings_validate()%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Bugs should be reported in the issue queue for the involved  module.

Answer (score 2):

You should report this in the module's issue queue.

Notice type errors are most of the time harmless and caused by sloppy programming or some edge case the developer didn't think of.

Comment: Hello guys, I maybe have a solution for the problem.
http://drupal.org/node/1145766
In post #28 you have to download a patch that fixes the problem but I do not have a idea how to install this..

Comment: @user4183: ```patch -p1 < patchfile``` see [patch](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_patch.htm) for more details

Comment: Hello guys
I thought the -p1 tag was only if you want to patch modules in the core. So I only typed patch < name.patch and i got following error Hunk #1 FAILED at 157

Comment: Hello guys problems solved without the -p1 attribute in the tag. Patchfile was corrupt, downloaded a new one and everything worked. Thanks